# How to edit listview item from another form

Tags: c#

on adjust quantity button on form1 i have

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adjust fr = new adjust();
        int i = 0;
        ListViewItem it = listView1.SelectedItems[i];
        it.Remove();
        string v1 = it.SubItems[1].Text;
        decimal v2 = decimal.Parse(it.SubItems[2].Text);
        decimal v3 = decimal.Parse(it.SubItems[3].Text);
        fr.itemcodetxt.Text = v1;
        fr.currentquantity.Text = v2.ToString();
        fr.pricetxt.Text = v3.ToString();

        fr.ShowDialog();


    }
```

and on form2(adjust) i have this code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Form1 f = new Form1();


        //Is the error i recieve here
        ListViewItem item = f.listView1.Items[1]; //Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
        string itemcode = item.SubItems[1].Text;
        decimal itemquantity = decimal.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text);
        decimal pr = decimal.Parse(item.SubItems[3].Text);
        decimal totalp = decimal.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text) * decimal.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        totalp = decimal.Parse(item.SubItems[4].Text);

        var itm = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = "1";
        item.SubItems.Add(itemcodetxt.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(pr.ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(totalp.ToString());

        f.listView1.Items.Add(item);

    }
```

Comment: new creates a *new* instance.

Comment: It is better not to operate on GUI data directly. You could (should) bind the listview to some structure (such as a DataTable, list, etc.) that holds the data and operate on the structure not on the GUI control.

Comment: please teach me that i don't have idea

Comment: You need to determine what client data source you will use, then determine if you can declare it as part of 'static' class (if that suits your case), then perform the other operations like fetching data, binding and editing. See an example of listview binding here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10008/Data-binding-a-ListView

Comment: More on the binding concept is here:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms

Comment: Not fully sure where you at but maybe my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920102/update-gridview-column-values-from-another-form-in-c-sharp-winform/32921060#32921060) can help you to clarify your question.